# clojurescript thread macro nested vector problem

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

this is my function

```
(defn foo
      []
      (->> (conj (:countries list1)                         ;; ["UK" "USA" "IND"]
                 (:countries list2)                         ;; ["AUS" "NZ"]
                 (:countries list3)                         ;; "FRA"
                 )
           (some-other-operations)))
```

comment shows the data they fetches and I'm expecting my result to be like this

```
["UK" "USA" "IND" "AUS" "NZ" "FRA"]
```

but i don't why it gives me output like this

```
["UK" "USA" ["AUS" "NZ"] "FRA"]
```

it works fine though if i remove list2. then it produces output like this

```
["UK" "USA" "FRA"]
```

anyone any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: I think your life would be alot easier, if you would normalize the data, so that list3 as well reurns a vector for countries. Then you can run `(mapcat :countries [list1 list2 list3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the root problem, as i see it, is an irregular `:countries` value type, being collection or atom in different cases. What i would propose, is ensure the `:contries` is always a collection and use `concat`. In case you don't have control over the data type (which often happens), i'd propose utility concatenation function, something like that:

```
(defn concat* [& xs]
  (reduce (fn [acc x]
            ((if (sequential? x) into conj) acc x))
          [] xs))

user> (concat* ["UK" "USA" "IND"] ["AUS" "NZ"] "FRA")
;;=> ["UK" "USA" "IND" "AUS" "NZ" "FRA"]
```

as for me, i would discourage using `flatten` in production code, since it may lead to the whole bunch of errors when data type changes.

Comment: Could you please describe which errors may come up using flatten when the data type changes?

Comment: @Gernot , the obvious one, is when you turn the country from string to tuple, adding a phone code for example. Tuples are not uncommon in functional programming, really. Like `["USA" "+1"]`. And now you are getting  `["UK" "+44" "USA" "+1" "IND" "+XXX" "AUS" "+XXY" "NZ" "+XXZ"]`, which is really not what you want. This can happen when update a DB query which in turn changes the return value form.

Answer (score 2):

First two values are lists, but the third value is not a list (FRA). If it were, you could use `concat`.

```
(concat list1 list2 list3)
```

If not, then

```
(let [list1 ["UK" "USA" "IND"]
      list2 ["AUS" "NZ"]
      v3    "FRA"]
    `(~@list1 ~@list2 ~v3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [flatten](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten) the result to "unpack" the nested vector that is now inside the collection.

Comment: using (comp vec flatten conj) in place of conj works for me thanks much !!

Comment: @NavneetSingh I think the answer from leetwinski should be the accepted one as it addresses the possible issues introduced by using flatten

Comment: tbh i didn't understand the code he wrote earlier as i'm new to functional programming but it is clear to me now. Thanks !!!